# How do I track the order of presses?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

I have a sequence of flashing buttons, after its done the user has to repeat this order. I want to detect if the correct order was pressed, or detect if the order the user pressed is incorrect, (the user has to go in the same sequence).

How would I go about doing this? I have no idea. Please explain as simply as possible, I am very new to this.

PS I am using kobold2D.

Answer (score 0):

Create an `NSMutableArray` instance variable. When the game/level starts you empty it. When the user taps a button you add some identifier to the array (such as the buttons number or title, or even the button object itself). Finally, implement a method that compares this array with a prepared array (the correct solution).

**EDIT:**

Here is a starting point.

```
@interface SomeClassWhereYourButtonsAre
// Array to store the tapped buttons' numbers:
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *tappedButtons;
// Array to store the correct solution:
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *solution;
...
@end
```

```
@implementation SomeClassWhereYourButtonsAre
...
- (void)startGame {
    self.tappedButtons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    // This will be the correct order for this level:
    self.solution = @[@3, @1, @2, @4];
    // You probably will have to load this from some text or plist file, 
    // and not hardcode it.
}
- (void)buttonTapped:(Button *)b {
    // Assuming your button has an ivar called number of type int:
    [self.tappedButtons addObject:@(b.number)];
    BOOL correct = [self correctSoFar];
    if (!correct) {
        if (self.tappedButtons.count == self.solution.count) {
            // success!
        } else {
            // correct button, but not done yet
    } else {
        // wrong button, game over.
    }
}
- (BOOL)correctSoFar {
    // if he tapped more buttons then the solution requires, he failed.
    if (self.tappedButtons.count > self.solution.count)
        return NO;
    for (int i = 0; i < self.tappedButtons; i++) {
        if (self.tappedButtons[i] != self.solution[i]) {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
@end
```

Comment: Could you give me an example? Thanks!